Looking for a text where Lenin allegedly recommended that wage earners should invest their money in financial assets
I remember reading a short text a couple of years ago (possibly on social media), where the author stated that Lenin used to recommend that wage earners should invest their money in financial assets, so that in the event of a financial crisis it would incite them to revolt.
Unfortunately I forgot the reference and cannot find it again, so maybe I misremember a part of the statement made by the author. However, I clearly remember reading something along these lines, and I think my description above captures the gist of it.
I'm not familiar with Lenin's texts (or with Marxist texts in general), and this statement surprised me quite a bit, as I would have assumed that Marxists would argue against participating this way in the capitalist system. On the top of that, I can't find online documents where Lenin mentions this idea. So I'm quite skeptical, but maybe it's simply ignorance from my part, and it's possible that I used the wrong search terms.
Does anyone know in what text or speech Lenin could have make such an argument in favor of this idea?
Thank you.

This appears to be an incorrect claim, as per different google and AI searches.

For working people in Lenin's time, doing so wouldn't have been as easy as today

@PeteW Certainly, that's one more reason why I'm skeptical of the claim.

I've seen many cases on social media where people would put random "quotes" attributed to random people to fit their agenda. But, as President Lincoln famously said, don't believe everything you read on the Internet.

@littleadv And that's why I'm highly skeptical and ask this question in the first place. Sure, that might be a difficult question to answer if the claim is false, but I don't think that trying to find out the truth about it warrants downvotes, though. In the meantime,  I keep searching where I saw this claim to ask directly the person who said that, and will post an answer to my own question if I find out anything.

Isn't there Skeptics@SE for that?

@littleadv I just read their help pages, and it's my understanding that this would be off-topic on their website. On a side note, I see there's an ongoing vote to close the question. Fair enough., I get it might be too difficult to answer. If it's closed, I'll try to gather additional info to improve the question, but I'm not very optimistic about it.

Lenin's style of writing is quite polemic most of the time, sometimes bordering on sarcastic. Maybe someone intentionally misunderstood the context?

I'd also think that this is a typical question for sketics, if you can suppor the notability a bit more.

@Toffomat This is the problem, I can't even find again the text where I read this claim, so I don't think it's likely to meet their notability criteria. I'm still searching though. It seems that the claim isn't familiar to anyone on this website, so I remain very skeptical. This is not a big deal if the question is closed, if I find more info later I'll still be able to edit the question for it to be hopefully reopened. I don't understand the downvotes though.

Bukharin called on the peasants to enrich themselves and grow their farms. It's a stretch but perhaps this quote went through many rounds of telephone to become a quote by Lenin about workers and financial assets...

@xyldke Thanks for the reference! I'll look into that, though I clearly remember that the author was mentioning Lenin. It's entirely possible that they mistook him for another author (assuming they just didn't make it up, which is another possibility).
